# I want to create new table based on distinct element of column?

Tags: powerbi

I have categorical column imported in Powerbi and want to create new table based condition:

**Distinct count of Column[Element]>=2**.

```
| Column |
|--------|
| A      |
| A      |
| B      |
| C      |
| A      |
| B      |
```

Required Table

```
| Column |
|--------|
| A      |
| B      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way to this, but you can do the following steps

1. Create a measure in you Main_Table like so - `Count Element= COUNT('Main_ Table'[Column Name])>2`
2. Click on New Table in modeling tab and use the following formula:  `New Table = FILTER(CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('Main table'[Column Name])),[Count Element])`

Or you can use the following formula in one go

```
New Table = FILTER(CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('Main Table'[Column Name])),CALCULATE(COUNTA('Main Table'[Column Name]),ALLEXCEPT('Main Table','Main Table'[Column Name]))>2)
```

## Old

There is a basic DAX formula to extract distinc values of a column as a separate table. You need to click on **New Table** in the modeling tab and use the Distinc Formula like below:

```
Table_Name = DISTINCT(Existing_Table[Column_Name])
```

Comment: But how do i used condition of including only those cell whose count is greater than 2.

Comment: I have edited the answer @Maqsud. This should give you your output